# Cant get value from cakephp observe field

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have been trying to pass paging value from a select box to one of my controller for paging
I want to do this by ajax so i used cakephp observe field.
My code is as follows:

```
$options = array('10' => '10', '20' => '20', '50' => '50', '100' => '100');
echo $form->input('pagecount', array(
    'id'      => 'pagecount', 'name' => 'pagecount', 'type' => 'select',
    'options' => $options, 'selected' => '10', 'div' => false, 'label' => false
));
echo $ajax->observeField('pagecount', array(
    'with'      => '$F("pagecount")', 'url' => array(
        'controller' => 'templates', 'action' => 'themes', $template_id
    ), 'update' => 'themeTable', 'indicator' => 'loaderIDast'
));
```

Problem is that i cannot get the value of the selected option in the controller that i have mentioned in the url param of the observeField.I have used the **with** param of the observefield for this.I can see the selected value under the parameters tab of my firefox net panel.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax implies Cake 1.2 but your question is tagged with 1.3. Which are you using?

The Ajax helper is deprecated in Cake 1.3 and functionality is dodgy at best. Most of its appropriate functionality was ported to the Js helper, or the Html / Form helpers. The `observeField` method is deprecated and does not have a synonym in the Js helper.

If my guess is right and you're using Cake 1.3, my suggestion would be, just write out the client-side observer in ordinary javascript and pass the result back to your server-side code for processing in the likewise ordinary manner. Fancy generation of code snippets is not really suitable for one-shot or highly mutable situations like this anyway, it doesn't really DRY up anything (which is the main point of the Js helper.) Mostly it just introduces a couple of extra layers of complexity when you're trying to debug.

HTH. :)

Answer (score 0):

The Ajax helper is deprecated in Cake 1.3 and functionality is dodgy at best. Most of its appropriate functionality was ported to the Js helper, or the Html / Form helpers. The observeField method is deprecated and does not have a synonym in the Js helper.